# jQuery Validate: Validate that one field, or both fields of a pair are required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that I am trying to validate that has two fields:

```
<div class="entryForm">
    <div class="formField">
        <label for="fieldEmailAddress">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="fieldEmailAddress" id="fieldEmailAddress"/>
    </div>
    <div class="formField">
        <label for="fieldMobileNumber">Mobile number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fieldMobileNumber" id="fieldMobileNumber"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery Validation wireup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form1').validate({ rules: { fieldMobileNumber: { phoneUS: true } } });
    });
</script>
```

**What I'd like to do is add an additional validation rule that says: *the form is not valid if both fieldEmailAddress and fieldMobileNumber are blank.***  In other words, I'd like to make it such that at least one of either fieldEmailAddress or fieldMobileNumber is required. It seems like most of the jQuery Validation custom methods are designed to only work for one field at a time - I need to validate both.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it need to be done inside the "validate" plugin?

Comment: @doitlikejustin -  I'm using jQuery validate to validate the current form.  I think there's a way to use jQuery validate to validate just those fields based on my rules, and I think i could use something around it.  I'll take a closer look at your answer tomarrow (EOD here), but it looks super duper promising.

Comment: Simply use the `require_from_group` method included in the `additional-methods.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) and use the `require_from_group` method.

```
require_from_group: [x, '.class']

// x = number of items required from a group of items.

// .class = class assigned to every form element included in the group.
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            fieldMobileNumber: {
                phoneUS: true,
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
            },
            fieldEmailAddress: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
            }
        },
        groups: {
            theGroup: 'fieldMobileNumber fieldEmailAddress'
        }
    });

});
```

Add `class="mygroup"` to each input you need to group together...

```
<input type="email" name="fieldEmailAddress" id="fieldEmailAddress" class="mygroup" />
```

And finally, optionally use the `groups` option to lump the messages into one...

```
groups: {
    theGroup: 'fieldMobileNumber fieldEmailAddress'
}
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/CYZZy/

If you don't like where the validation message is placed, that's where you'd tweak it using the `errorPlacement` callback function.

Comment: I wish they had more documentation on the additional-methods file.  I'll make sure to peruse that next time.  Thank you!

Comment: @J.Polfer, you're welcome.  Yes, it's not documented well, but you can find [instructions within the comments of the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js)

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the Validate plugin and do a check like the following:

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
    var email = $('#fieldEmailAddress');
    var phone = $('#fieldMobileNumber');

    if(email.val() == '' && phone.val() == '') {
        alert('Fill out both fields');
    }
    else if(email.val() == '') {
        alert('Email, please...');
    }
    else if(phone.val() == '') {
        alert('Phone, please...');      
    }
    else {
        alert('Yay!');
    }   
});
```