# Validate a form if only one on two fields is not empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using Jquery Validate plugin and i have two fields like these :

```
<input id="nbextr" name="nbextr" class="form-control" type="text" title="Ex: 3" 
value="" tabindex="3"  />
<input id="nbextr2" name="nbextr2" class="form-control" type="text" title="Ex: 3" value="" tabindex="4"  />
```

I need that only one of these two fields is not empty.

And i don't find a basic solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation - Two fields, only required to fill in one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137844/jquery-validation-two-fields-only-required-to-fill-in-one) - you cannot have looked very hard

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate: Validate that one field, or both fields of a pair are required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993067/jquery-validate-validate-that-one-field-or-both-fields-of-a-pair-are-required)

Comment: You would use the `require_from_group` method included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).  See [this link for usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993067/jquery-validate-validate-that-one-field-or-both-fields-of-a-pair-are-required).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to do it with validate but i did the trick like this :

```
$("#nbextr").blur(function() {
    if($("#nbextr").val().length > 0){
    $("#nbextr2").val("");
    }
});
```

And the same for the other field.

Comment: You asked for a jQuery Validate solution and your answer has nothing to do with that.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993067/jquery-validate-validate-that-one-field-or-both-fields-of-a-pair-are-required

Comment: I know, thanks. but i was need a solution so i do that for waiting. Your link is for validate at least one field. So only nbextr or nbextr2. Like a Radio button.