# jQuery Validation plugin. Add new rules to existing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have project where I use jQuery validation.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form action="/" id="MyForm" onsubmit="greeting()">
    <input type="checkbox" value="val1"  name="dner" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function greeting() {
    return $("#MyForm").valid();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MyForm").validate({ onsubmit: true }); //If comment this code line, it work!!!
    $.validator.addMethod("MyFunction", function (value, element) {
        if ($("input:checked").length > 0) { return true } else { alert("Пустое поле"); return false; }
    },
    "");
    $("#MyForm").rules("add", { dner:{ MyFunction :true}});
});
</script>
```

It work, when I comment one line of code. It is very important, because in my project I have a set new rules for validation, and I can't remake it. How I can add new rules to existing rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your code**:

```
//If comment this code line, it work!!!
$("#MyForm").validate({ onsubmit: true });
```

If you comment out that entire line, you'll remove the *initialization method* of the plugin!

It's a moot point since your code is not working in either case.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vEAwQ/) or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vEAwQ/1/).

You'll have to rectify the following issues:

---

1)  `onsubmit: true` is already the ***default*** *behavior*, so by setting it to `true`, you break the plugin.  Just leave this option out if you want validation to occur upon clicking the `submit` button.

[See documentation for `onsubmit`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

> ***onsubmit** (default: true): 
> Validate the form on submit. Set to `false` to use only other events for validation.
>   Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation. **A boolean `true` is not a valid value**.*

---

2)  Your code: `$("#MyForm").rules("add"...`.

You are not supposed to attach the `.rules()` method to the `form`.  You attach it only to a `field` element...

```
$('input[name="dner"]').rules("add", {
    MyFunction: true
});
```

See [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

To apply this method to several fields at once, use the jQuery `.each()`...

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        MyFunction: true
    });
});
```

---

3)  You do not need an inline `submit` handler:  `onsubmit="greeting()"`.  Inline JavaScript is wholly unnecessary when using jQuery.  Besides, a `submit` handler will interfere with the plugin's built-in `submit` handler.  If you need to execute something upon the `submit` event when using this plugin, use the `submitHandler` callback function...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // fire this code when a valid form is submitted
    return false;  // prevent default form action, e.g. when using ajax()
}
```

If you need to fire code when the form is not valid, use the `invalidHandler` callback...

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // fire this code when an invalid form is submitted
}
```

See [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for examples.

---

4)  Your custom method can be condensed...

```
$.validator.addMethod("MyFunction", function (value, element) {
   return ($("input:checked").length > 0) 
}, "Пустое поле");
```

If you'd rather use an `alert()` than the `label` message, you can put that back. Although I don't recommend using an `alert()` as part of any modern design.

---

**DEMO with all changes applied**:  http://jsfiddle.net/sqKta/

Comment: You suggested.                                       $('input[name="dner"]').rules("add", {
    MyFunction: true
});                                                                Can I implement rule function to not input field? Because I have several checkboxes, and I want to check this is group of checkbox.

Comment: @higgs.boson, a checkbox **is** an input field.  See my edited answer where I show how you can use `.rules('add')` on multiple elements at once.

Comment: I want to check whether the selected at least one item in the group of checkbox. How can I do that?

Comment: @higgs.boson, you never mentioned anything about this in your OP.  However, you can include the `additional-methods.js` file and use the `require_from_group` method.  The instructions are embedded in the code comments of that file.  See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18994248/594235

Comment: my  project very large and I posted only important moment. Is there easy way to make an easy validate of several fields? Thank you very much anyway!!!!!

Comment: @higgs.boson, I fully answered your original question.  Please "accept" my answer and feel free to post a whole new question.  As per this site's guidelines, each question should be concise.