# jquery validation plugin for form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form having two fields 
`string email`  and `file type` file (one of the two is mandatory).
I am validating the form with following code,

```
$("#addOrganizationMembersForm").validate({
        rules : {
            csv : {
                required : "#emails:empty",
                extension: "xls|csv"
            },
            emails : {
                required : "#csv:empty"
            }
        },
        messages : {
            csv : {
                required : 'Upload a csv or xls file',
                extension : 'Only csv files are allowed',
            },
            emails : {
                required : 'Enter one or more comma seperated emails',
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is validating both fields (But for me if one of the two fields has value i.e email or csv file, then form is valid)

Kindly help me, what is wrong with this code

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate: Validate that one field, or both fields of a pair are required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993067/jquery-validate-validate-that-one-field-or-both-fields-of-a-pair-are-required)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("#addOrganizationMembersForm").validate({
     rules : {
            csv : {
                required : function(){
                              return $("#emails").is(':empty')
                           },
                extension: "xls|csv"
            },
            emails : {
                required : function(){
                              return $("#csv").is(':empty')
                           },
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks rohan for replying. i have already tried this, and the thing is if i add console.debug($("#emails").is(':empty')) statement before the return statement, every time it returns true. same occurs for csv.

Comment: @Shahzeb: That's really weird, there may be some conflicting id in your DOM. I tried only "$("#emails").is(':empty');" in place of function(){return $("#emails").is(':empty')}, and worked for me.

Comment: @sanki said `right` check your `DOM` once and `confirm` that you have `unique id's`

Comment: @sanki and Rohan thanks for your help, i replaced the .is(":empty") by  return ($("#emails").val() == null || $("#emails").val() == "") and it works.

Comment: @Shahzeb: Nice tweak :)

Comment: Just use the `required_from_group` rule from [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).

Answer (score 1):

**Quote OP's Comment**:

> *"Thanks rohan for replying. i have already tried this, and the thing is if i add `console.debug($("#emails").is(':empty'))` statement before the `return` statement, every time it returns `true`. same occurs for `csv`."*

When you have two fields where the `required` rule on each is dependent upon the other being empty, there are timing issues... you satisfy one field but then you might have to re-trigger validation on the other to clear the error.

However, if you include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js), you can just use the `require_from_group` rule which already does exactly what you want.  (*Must use plugin version 1.11.1 or later*)

```
$("#addOrganizationMembersForm").validate({
    rules: {
        csv: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
            extension: "xls|csv"
        },
        emails: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
        }
    },
    messages: {
        csv: {
            require_from_group: 'Upload a csv or xls file',
            extension: 'Only csv files are allowed',
        },
        emails: {
            require_from_group: 'Enter one or more comma seperated emails',
        }
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/h9WpL/**